# Is it possible to show button states in Eclipse Android Gui builder?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, gui-builder

I'm designing buttons with selector now. For testing the design I need to run application and Log into the application, navigate to the view and so on ... You know, It is not very comfortable for me.

Is it possible to show the button states (for example: pressed) in the Eclipse Android GUI builder? (because I only see the default style.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse view is not a true representation and you need to see your design on a device if you want to see how it actually looks.

You should create a test app that has your buttons on the first activity so you do not need to go through any navigation or login procedures.

Comment: I don't forget, only give the change to the community to help me :) Thx, again.